# Anonymous function in Select

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function

I'm a bit confused with the C# syntax of an anonoymous function call from a lambda expression.

I have the following code now which works fine:

```
private string[] IniLineFormatter(string input)
{
  return input.Split(":=".ToCharArray());
}

...

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(thisIniFile).Select(l => IniLineFormatter(l) ).ToList();
```

But how can I reformat this code to use an anonymous, inline function instead of the named `IniLineFormatter` function?

Comment: any language? c#

Comment: yes, supposed to be in C#

Answer (score 3):

Simple use `{ }`:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(thisIniFile).Select(l =>
{
    return l.Split(":=".ToCharArray());
}).ToList();
```

Everything before `=>` are your parameters. If you need multiple use `(p1, p2) =>`

Since your code is a one liner, you can also write:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(thisIniFile)
            .Select(l => l.Split(":=".ToCharArray())) // return is by convention
            .ToList();
```